# Why when I remove $(document).ready, autocomplete function got recognized?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a page with `autocomplete` function from jQuery UI, but I was getting the following error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'autocomplete'

I was pulling my hairs because everything seemed OK, but I still getting this error, here is the code:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="tags">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AutoCompleteSearch",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.ProductName, value: item.ProductName};
                        }));

                    }
                });
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

nothing worked until I removed the `$(document).ready` part, I was wondering what does this has to do with anything? why when I removed the `$(document).ready` suddenly autocomplete function got recognized?

Comment: can you replicate this error on http://jsbin.com ? It seems to be working here http://jsbin.com/verotidahe/edit?html,output

Comment: Looks like if you are not into `<head>` tag

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `onReady` if you type your code after the rendered html because the element exists already. That's because it works without it.

Comment: Thanks kmsdev, can you elaborate why it doesn't work with it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not close the `$(document).ready(function(){})` with `;` (semi-colon).

Now coming to your point, `$(document).ready();` is used when an event is triggered like : `.click(), .blur(), .change()` etc. `$(document).ready()` means you can not tigger an event until the page (document) is completely ready.

But the way you declared the `autocomplete()`, here no event is triggered. That's why it is working without `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: It still gives me an error even with semi-colon, I know what document.ready is for, but this error seemed weird.